# Use DI in Data Access Layer with ApplicationDbContext (netcore 2.0)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have some problem with `DI` (`Dependancy Injection`). My project is on `netcore 2.0` and has few layers (standard N-Tier Architecture). I'm trying to move `EF Core 2` from `Presentation Layer` to `Data Access Layer` and I have created the following classes in `DAL`:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Implementation.MySql.Contexts 
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder     optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql")
            );
        }

        public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I prepared base class for all `DAL` engines:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Implementation.MySql
{
    public class BaseEngine : IBaseEngine
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        protected ApplicationDbContext Db => _context;

        public BaseEngine(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

So, my common engine should look like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Implementation.MySql
{
    public class TestEngine : BaseEngine
    {
        public List<Test> GetTestList()
        {   
            return Db.Test.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get error, BaseEngine needs parameter to be passed in constructor and I don't want to create all instances manually, I need somehow use `Dependancy Injection` that automatically creates instances of `ApplicationDbContext` and `IConfiguration` when `BaseEngine` and `ApplicationDbContext` will be created..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public interface for `ApplicationDbContext`, like `IApplicationDbContext`. Put that in the constructor for `BaseEngine` instead of the concrete class. Make the `BaseEngine` constructor protected. The `BaseEngine` constructor should look like:

```
protected BaseEngine(IApplicationDbContext context)
```

Then, since `TestEngine` is derived from `BaseEngine`, and `BaseEngine` requires a constructor argument, you have to pass that in from the `TestEngine` constructor like:

```
public TestEngine(IApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
```